# nzsql - Using a defined variable inside of a string

Tags: netezza

I'm running into a bit of a snag using Netezza's `nzsql` tool when it comes to using [internal variables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_nzsql_command.html).  The documentation mentions how to set those variables, `\set varname value` but doesn't make clear how to use them in any meaningful way.

I've worked out that they can be used within queries, but so far I can only use them as identifiers, not strings.

For example, this works fine:

```
DB.INST1(INST1)=> \set COLNAME 'table_name'

DB.INST1(INST1)=> SELECT :COLNAME FROM _v_sys_columns LIMIT 1;
         TABLE_NAME
----------------------------
 _V_TABLE_ONLY_STORAGE_STAT
(1 row)

DB.INST1(INST1)=> \p
SELECT table_name FROM _v_sys_columns LIMIT 1;
```

But this doesn't:

```
DB.INST1(INST1)=> \set TABLE_NAME 'table_to_search_for'

DB.INST1(INST1)=> SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = :TABLE_NAME;
ERROR:  Attribute 'TABLE_TO_SEARCH_FOR' not found

DB.INST1(INST1)=> \p
SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = table_to_search_for;
```

And neither does this (it uses `:TABLE_NAME` as a text literal, not its contents):

```
DB.INST1(INST1)=> \set TABLE_NAME 'table_to_search_for'

DB.INST1(INST1)=> SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = ':TABLE_NAME';
 OWNER | CREATEDATE
-------+------------
(0 rows)

DB.INST1(INST1)=> \p
SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = ':TABLE_NAME';
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm hoping to do?  The result I'm hoping to achieve is having nzsql run the following query:

```
SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = 'table_to_search_for';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** embed the contents of a variable in a string.  The trick is making a new variable (`quoted_foo` in the below example) which contains a single quote, your variable's contents, and another single quote.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column LIKE '%ello%';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
(1 row)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo ello
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set quoted_foo '\'' :foo '\''
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :quoted_foo
'ello'

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column LIKE '%' || :quoted_foo || '%';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
(1 row)
```

For more about session variables in `nzsql` including using variables as part of table and column names, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270571/477563).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the contents of a variable as a literal in nzsql you need to include an additional set of single quotes, escaped with backslashes, around the literal text when you set the variable.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \set tvar '\'BLAH\''
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select :tvar col_alias;
 COL_ALIAS
-----------
 BLAH
(1 row)
```

Updating this with an example more relevant to your situation.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table var_table (col1 bigint);
CREATE TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \set TABLE_NAME '\'VAR_TABLE\''
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> SELECT owner, createdate FROM _v_table WHERE tablename = :TABLE_NAME; 
 OWNER |     CREATEDATE
-------+---------------------
 ADMIN | 2015-01-13 06:52:36
(1 row)
```

Comment: So... it looks like the answer is no, you can't use variables inside of strings.  `nzsql` just doesn't support it.

Comment: I think that's technically correct.  You have to put the string in the variable rather than the variable in the string. I realized my answer wasn't as useful for your specific question as it could have been, so updating that.

Comment: It took me almost a year but I finally figured out how to embed a variable in a string.  Thanks for your help, it pushed me in the right direction!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34270716/477563