# How do I use session variables in Netezza nzsql?

Tags: netezza, nzsql

1. How do I create and use session variables in Netezza `nzsql`?
2. How can I use session variables as part of strings?

   - Can I concatenate session variables with strings?
   - Can I embed session variables in strings?
3. How can I use them as part of table names or column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic Variable Usage

The [documentation](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_internal_slash_options.html) for session variables in Netezza `nzsql` is somewhat lacking.
It states that in order to set a variable within a script or at the `nzsql` prompt, you use `\set`.

```
\set var value
```

You can also specify the variable at the command line.  This is useful for passing variables into scripts.

```
nzsql -v var=value
```

Within your session or script, you can access the value of that variable as `:var`

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo example_table

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \d :foo
                       Table "EXAMPLE_TABLE"
   Attribute    |         Type          | Modifier | Default Value
----------------+-----------------------+----------+---------------
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN | CHARACTER VARYING(16) |          |
Distributed on hash: "EXAMPLE_COLUMN"

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM :foo;
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
```

---

### Advanced Variable Usage

The `\set` command also has undocumented capabilities that add greater flexibility.
In reality, `\set` takes **all** values passed to it and concatenates them together.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo bar baz qux
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
barbazqux
```

The command also supports quoting in a manner similar to shell scripts which allows you to include whitespace within your variables.
Be careful though, quoted and unquoted strings will still be concatenated with each other.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo 'bar baz qux'
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
bar baz qux

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo 'bar baz' qux
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
bar bazqux
```

Double quoting also works to preserves whitespace.  However, the double quotes will still be preserved in the variable.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo "bar baz qux"
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
"bar baz qux"

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo "bar baz" qux
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
"bar baz"qux
```

Of course, the different types of quoting can be mixed:

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo "Hello World" 'Goodbye World'
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
"Hello World"Goodbye World
```

---

### Single Quotes

Properly embedding single quotes in a `\set` command can be difficult.
Incidentally, because double quotes are always preserved, they rarely present a problem.

Single quotes within an unquoted word will be preserved.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo bar'baz'qux
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
bar'baz'qux
```

Single quotes within a quoted word may result in issues.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo 'bar'baz'qux'
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
barbaz'qux'
```

Single quotes within a doubly quoted value are preserved.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo "This'll work fine!"
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
"This'll work fine!"
```

Single quotes on their own need to be quoted **and** escaped.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo '
parse error at end of line

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo \'
Invalid command \'. Try \? for help.

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo '\''
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
'
```

**When in doubt:** single quote the phrase and escape all remaining single quotes with backslashes.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo '\'bar\'baz\'qux\''
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :foo
'bar'baz'qux'
```

---

### Variables In Identifiers

Occasionally you will need to use a variable as part of an identifier (i.e. a column or table name).
Consider the following example table and variable:

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table;
 BAR_COLUMN  | QUX_COLUMN
-------------+-------------
 This is bar | This is qux
(1 row)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo bar
```

In this example, you want to select `bar_column` using your variable `:foo` (which contains `bar`) and the text `_column`.
The following will not work:

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT :foo_column FROM example_table;
foo_column:
ERROR:  'SELECT  FROM example_table;'
error            ^ found "FROM" (at char 9) expecting an identifier found a keyword
```

The above example fails because `nzsql` cannot determine where the variable name ends (`:foo`) and the remaining column (`_column`) name begins.
To fix this, you need to make a new variable with `\set` by concatenating the value of `:foo` and the rest of the column name:

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set fixed_foo :foo _column
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :fixed_foo
bar_column

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT :fixed_foo FROM example_table;
 BAR_COLUMN
-------------
 This is bar
(1 row)
```

If the variable contains the *end* of the identifier you wish to use, no intermediate variables need to be created.
In that specific case, `nzsql` will properly expand the variable (e.g. `column_:foo` -> `column_bar`).

---

### Stringification

Sometimes you will need to use the contents of a variable as a string.
Consider the following example table and variable:

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table;
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
 Whatever
 Something
(3 rows)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo Something
```

If you simply quote the variable within the statement then it will be treated as literal text.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column = 'Something';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Something
(1 row)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column = ':foo';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
(0 rows)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \p
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column = ':foo';
```

If you leave the variable unquoted then it will be used as an identifier.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column = :foo;
ERROR:  Attribute 'SOMETHING' not found
```

To fix this, you need to use `\set` and your knowledge of quoting to create a usable variable.
You can accomplish this by making a new variable by combining a single quote (properly escaped!), the variable's contents, and another single quote.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set quoted_foo '\'' :foo '\''
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :quoted_foo
'Something'

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column = :quoted_foo;
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Something
(1 row)
```

If your variable needs to be used inside of a string, it may be easier to stringify your variable and use regular string concatenation.

```
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column LIKE '%ello%';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
(1 row)

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set foo ello
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \set quoted_foo '\'' :foo '\''
DB.TST(LLAMA)=> \echo :quoted_foo
'ello'

DB.TST(LLAMA)=> SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE example_column LIKE '%' || :quoted_foo || '%';
 EXAMPLE_COLUMN
----------------
 Hello World
(1 row)
```